# iOS FBSDKLogin Button text fade-in

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, uibutton

So I'm using Facebook's FBSDKLoginButton to create a button that will authenticate the user with Facebook.  However, it seems by default the button has an animation on it that fades in the text.  This looks great and all, but my other buttons don't have this effect, so there's a discrepancy there.  Any way to remove this fade in (or replicate it on my other buttons with the exact timing and style as the fb button)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want you own interface effects and styling instead of the drag and drop vanilla Button supplied by FB I suggest you use FBSDKLoginManager instead of FBSDKLoginButton so you call the API yourself to perform login or additional authorisations with your own UI.

You can find more details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3

Edit: If I have time over the weekend I'll update this answer with how this will looking in code. Fri - 5/JUN/15

Comment: yeh I was just wondering if there was a way to tweak the default FBSDKLoginButton slightly so I don't have to deal with all the other overhead of using LoginManager.  I mean everything is exactly how I want it except for that animation.

Comment: This is definitely a hack rather than a solution but you could place a UIButton over the facebook button and set userInteractionEnabled to NO. Then update its look from the observeProfileChange and observeTokenChange methods which respond to the FBLoginButton beneath your custom button. You can't change the supplied FB button though afaik.